# How can I treat nutrient burnt basil seedlings?

Tags: seedlings, soil-amendment, basil, manure

I grow basil plants from seed. They're approximately 1 month old. I gave them a little pigeon manure, and I think I burnt them. How can I normalize the soil and plant? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not tip burn This is too much light at some point in the past bleaching the leaves !

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good idea to apply raw manure to the soil around plants because of the risks associated with bacteria, and the heat generated by decomposition. It should be composted first.

Normally if there is excess nutrient present, it can be flushed out with water. If it's in solid form that may not be possible.

If this is nutrient burn, I wonder why the younger leaves are not seemingly affected.

Comment: Then maybe problem is not nutrient burn? How it's seems like? Maybe nutrient deficiency? Should I transplant seedlings to new soil?